# Show only author's own activity (Recently Published) post in wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I'm Working on a multi author blog. In dashboard wordpress shows all users post, activity and comment. I need to show only author's own post, comment and also activity of their own post only.

I've searched and found some codes, that is working on showing user's own comment and post. http://pastebin.com/pCBSRpyy

But in **Activity Tab (Recently Published)** is shows all other users post. Is there any filter function, that will show only author's own activity and list of his own Recently Published posts in wordpress dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for you....

```
       function posts_for_current_author($query) {
            global $user_level;

            if($query->is_admin && $user_level < 5) {
                global $user_ID;
                $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
                unset($user_ID);
            }
            unset($user_level);

            return $query;
        }
        add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

[Credit - WordPress Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-only-authors-posts-in-admin-panel-instead-of-all-posts)